# Linux/ File in linux and F_TLOCK issue

Tags: c, linux, file-io, fork

I read a book about files in Linux, and it gives the next example:

```
int main(char ** argv, int argc) {
  int stat;
  int fd = open("dugma1.txt", O_WRONLY, 0666);

  if (fork() == 0) {
    int fd2 = open("dugma1.txt", O_WRONLY, 0666);
    sleep(10);
    if (lockf(fd2, F_TLOCK, 17) >= 0) {
      write(fd2, "I was here second", 17);
    }
  } //if
  else {
    lockf(fd, F_TLOCK, 16);
    write(fd, "I was here first", 16);
    wait(&stat);    
  }
}
```

It says that the output will be:`I was here first`, and the reason: We don't close the file. But I didn't understand this explantion. We first write: `I was here first`, but why after the `sleep(10)` we will not go to this part of the code:

```
if (lockf(fd2, F_TLOCK, 17) >= 0) {
   write(fd2, "I was here second", 17);
}
```

`F_TLOCK` is a non-blocking, and for that we will succsses writing "I was here second".

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you got the arguments of `main()` in the wrong order. Should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: I would avoid using `lockf()`, since the relationship between `lockf()` and `fcntl()` locks is not standardized. In Linux `lockf()` is just a wrapper around `fcntl()`, but you cannot assume that holds for *all* systems. `fcntl()` locks are the only ones that work reliably over shared filesystems like NFS (and then only if the file server and all clients are correctly configured).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent executes `lockf(fd, F_TLOCK, 16)` on the opened file, locking the first `16` bytes. Then it writes the text inside and waits for the child to exit. It does not close the file and hence the lock remains. If there was a `close(fd);` in the parent's code after the `write()`, the lock would have been released but there isn't.

The child first sleeps for a while and when it tries to lock the first 17 bytes of the file but that fails since the parent still has the lock. That's why `lockf(fd2, F_TLOCK, 17)` fails with `EAGAIN` - the operation should be repeated later on. Errors are signalled by a return value of `-1` which makes the conditional in the child code not to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
lockf(fd2,F_TLOCK,17)
```

Encounters an error (EAGAIN) and therefore returns -1.  The value required to write to the file is equal to or greater than 0, not -1.  The test fails and the write never occurs.

Comment: Thank you, but why it return this error? I try to understand why this happen, and not what happen. Thanks.

Comment: It returns the error because the parent locked the file and left it locked.  The child cannot get past the lock, so it cannot write.  The child branches over the write.